# Json response to array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I want to convert my ajax json response into javascript array. I am not sure how i am able to do this. I tried split but it's not what i wanted. Please do help!

My AJAX Json response (This is in one string):

```
Array[Date:"[['2016-09-09',162], ['2016-12-04',145], ['2017-01-11',130]]"]
```

My desire outcome after pushing it in array:

```
var array = [['2016-09-09',162], ['2016-12-04',145], ['2017-01-11',130]];
```

Comment: `Array[Date:"..."]` … what is this?!

Comment: If I understand you get a literal string response? namely: "Array[Date:"[['2016-09-09',162], ['2016-12-04',145], ['2017-01-11',130]]"]"

Comment: You AJAX response is not JSON.

Comment: can you show you php code !?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to extract data from the string.

```js
var str = `Array[Date:"[['2016-09-09',162], ['2016-12-04',145], ['2017-01-11',130]]"]`;

// regex for your string pattern
var re = /\[\s?'(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})'\s?,\s?(\d+)\s?\]/g;
// array for result
var res = [],
  // variable for caching match
  m;

// iterate over the matches
while (m = re.exec(str)) {
  //push values into array
  res.push([m[1], +m[2]]); // use + prefix to convert into number
}

console.log(res);
```

[**Regex explanation here**](https://regex101.com/r/DUpL0I/1)

---

**FYI :** It would be better to update server-side code to generate a valid JSON string(it's easy to implement in all programming language, there would be a predefined function or library for that).

Comment: @lel : glad to help :)

Comment: hi @Pranav C Balan sorry to bother again, if ['2016-09-09',162] the back number have a decimal point e.g ['2016-09-09',1.62] or  ['2016-09-09',16.2] , how do i change the regax to match that?

Comment: @lel : `(\d+)` => `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

Answer (score -1):

if the AJAX response is a string, you can convert it using `JSON.parse(strSesponse)`